# Eloquent multiple has many through and inverse

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, relationship, has-many-through

(Laravel 4.2)

I have the following schema

- `A one to many B`
- `B one to many C`
- `C one to one D`

Now I know that `hasManyThrough` can be used to get `A one to many C`, but can I use it to get `A one to many D'?

The way I am doing is right now is getting C using `hasManyThrough` and then getting D from C using `hasOne()`.

Also is there a way get the inverse relationship, even for simple has many through?

Comment: ever found an answer to this ?

Comment: @darkylmnx Unfortunately no

Comment: i was hoping so... i have currently the same problem, and doing a raw sql join could be the answer but it would be very difficult to map the result to eloquent's model